# Proxy pdf from s3 and render it out inline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, proxy, dragonfly-gem

I am using dragonfly to handle my attachments and s3 to store the assets.

I know i can serve directly from s3 but my client has locked down internet access so cant access them. So what i need to do is proxy the images through my domain.

```
data = open(@training_doc.upload.remote_url).read
send_data data, :filename => @training_doc.upload.name
```

Thats what I have but it doesn't allow me to render it inline (in the tab its self) rather it downloads it which isn't ideal.

I know i can do this to render it inline but this isn't proxied

```
    redirect_to @training_doc.upload.remote_url(:expires => 2.hours.from_now, :query => {'response-content-disposition' => 'inline'})
```

I know in rails you can use send_file but that only works when you have it in the normal file system

Is their any other ways/ way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `send_data` method has a `disposition` option that can be set to `inline`:

```
data = open(@training_doc.upload.remote_url).read
send_data(data, 
  :filename    => @training_doc.upload.name,
  :type        => 'application/pdf',
  :disposition => 'inline'
)
```